# Xpages - Compute Xsp.properties to set theme

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

Hi I saw from another question that it's possible to set theme via (on beforePageLoad event)

```
if ( ! theme.equals(context.getSessionProperty("xsp.theme"))) {
        context.setSessionProperty("xsp.theme", theme);
        context.redirectToPage(context.getUrl().toSiteRelativeString(context));
    }
```

But was wondering whether it's possible to set values in xsp.properties via SSJS or Java ?

Would I need to build the DB after it's been set ?

Comment: Most EL expressions are valid within themes.

Comment: Hi Tim, do you have an example for an EL expression to set theme ?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question... please provide a bit more detail as to what you're trying to do, and why. Are you wanting to execute code at runtime that would change the theme for everyone instead of just for the current user?

Answer (score 0):

As Tim pointed out: EL is valid *inside* a theme, so you might create one theme and have your variations inside that theme using EL.